# Javascript Audio Play on body click

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a script that when anyone clicks on the body of the website, it will play an audio file.

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio("audiofile.mp3");
$( "body" ).click(function() {
audio.play();
});
</script>
```

Above is the code I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure why. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is as empty as you state it, since there is no HTML, you are not clicking on the body, but merely the document.

So:

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio("audiofile.mp3");
$(document).click(function() {
    audio.play();
});
</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: Sadly does not work. The page actually does have HTML. It's got <h1>'s across the page.

Comment: Ah, so can you post your entire code so I can take a look at it :)?
(Have you included jQuery in your code, for example?)

Comment: Nevermind! Cloudflare was caching the old webpage and I had to put it into Dev mode. ;)

Answer (score -1):

> Hey try this set up and see if it does the trick:

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio1">
<source src= "audiofile.mp3">
</audio>
```

JS:

```
$( "body" ).click(function() {

        var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
        }else{
            audio.currentTime = 0
    }
    });
```